# Extract description rather than URL in calculated column to use it with another url

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Let's say the first column is UID having number 12345. You will be directed to the URL after you click on 12345.

The second column I am trying to create is like a URL to some website followed by 12345. I am trying calculated column which worked, but the only problem is it is picking up URL instead of 12345.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Been struggling for a while.

```
="<a href='https://website/="&[Column1]&"' target='_blank'>Snow link</a>'
```

**Update**

When I use this code

```
    {
       "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
       formatting.schema.json",
       "elmType": "a",
       "txtContent": "Display Text",
       "attributes": {
       "href": "='https://sm2.sn.westpac.com.au/nav_to.do? 
        uri=%2Fchange_request.do%3Fsys_id%3D' + [$CHG #.desc]",
        "target": "_blank"
      }
   }
```

The column shows no link and comes up as blank for all the rows.

[image: This is the test image]

I am referring to this column where the link is embedded to CHN in each row and from which we have to extract the CHN number not the URL.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the UID is a hyperlink column, correct?

Comment: Are you using HTML in calculated columns in **SharePoint Online**?  classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: Yes, I am using HTML in modern experience.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, for SharePoint online modern experience, you can use column JSON formatting

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Go to Change",
  "attributes": {
    "href": " = 'https://sm2.sn.westpac.com.au/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fchange_request.do%3Fsys_id%3D' + [$CHG #.desc]",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

**Note**: You need to use the **internal name** of your `CHG #` field in JSON. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Example**:

If initially while creating a list column you have given name like `CHG #` then its internal name in SharePoint will be changed something like: `CHG_x0020__x0023_`. You can find the exact internal name of your column using above link.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: The column CHG # is multiple lines of text and not hyperlink column, is this something that's causing the problem?

Comment: If it is "Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text" then it is not possible to extract description of link from this field using JSON formtting.

Comment: That's great. It's working now. The only problem is I am getting some garbage alphabets between the link and the description, like https://D    **%2F%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8 **
  CHG0061106 The bold characters are automatically getting added depending on the size of the CHG number. You can find the image here. [Imgur](https://imgur.com/V5XDlHR)

Comment: Sorry I mean to say because of **%2F%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8 ** the link does not work. After removing this it works. I googled and it may be becasue of copy paste the link from Microsoft tools, so I wrote down the link manually but still the link is not working because of this garbage. What do you think?

Comment: This is the issue with how you add the link. in browser URL, characters get encoded, check [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP). So, you need to make sure you are adding correct URL in your list columns and building it correctly in `href` attribute of above JSON code.

Comment: double checked the variable but still the same. You can find the code snippet and the hyperlink column snippet here [Imgur](https://imgur.com/DcUZcDA) and the hyperlink column snippet here [Imgur](https://imgur.com/0wgaSgQ) I am just getting this error %E2%80%8B at the end of the link

Comment: Might be some special character is added at the end of Display text of URL. First try using simple Display text like '12345' or something (by entering it manually) and see if it generates the URL in correct format....Then you check with your change numbers

Comment: it worked out, thanks!

Comment: Hi @StupendousEnzio, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.